# Serve content from first domain's subdirectory on another domain using Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I have a website, say `domain1.example`, deployed on an Amazon EC2 machine with apache2.
I want to point `domain2.example` to `domain1.example/path`.
Basically like this:
`domain2.example` -> `domain1.example/path`
`domain2.example/one` -> `domain1.example/path/one`
`domain2.example/two/page` -> `domain1.example/path/two/page`
(Without changing the URL in the browser's address bar)

I have tried these methods:

1. Adding a rewrite rule to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName "domain2.example"
        ServerAdmin email@domain1.example
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.example/path/$1 [P]
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Adding a rewrite rule to `.htaccess` in the project folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.example/path/$1 [P]
```

Neither of them works. Both domains are serving the root folder. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And what does "Neither of them work" actually mean? Exactly? Did you receive back unexpected content? Did an error get pointed out? Which one? Did the universe implode when you made a test request?

Comment: One _guess_ here would be that you receive back a http status 500. Which might be caused by the issue that the proxy modules are not loaded into the http server. An issue which would clearly be pointed out in your http server's error log file. But as said: that is just a _guess_ ...

Comment: Redirects by definition change the URL. What you are looking for is not a redirect. You want to serve the same content on URLs under two different domains. I edited your question to remove the term  "redirect".

Comment: @arkascha By that I mean both domains are serving the same content (the root folder). Edited the question for clarification.

Comment: OK, so your rules most likely do not get applied at all. We cannot tell you why, we do not have access to that information.

Comment: If I understand your comment to the answer @StephenOstermiller gave low then I wonder why you can't simply use an internal rewrite rule instead of using those extremely expensive proxy rules...

Comment: "Adding a rewrite rule to .htaccess in the project folder" - How does the "project" folder fit into this? Where have you defined the `DocumentRoot`? The vHost you've posted only covers port 80, presumably you are accessing both domains over HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

I would implement this using separate virtual hosts for the two domains that have different document roots.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "domain1.example"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "domain2.example"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/path
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

While this will accomplish your goal, I would not recommend setting up websites like this.

- If both sites have `.htaccess` files they can conflict with each other.  You may see different behavior when accessing the content on the different domains because of which rules apply to in the two scenarios.
- Search engines prefer to find content on just one "canonical" URL.   When you serve the same content on multiple domains it can confuse search engines and hurt your SEO.

Comment: But the site is using PHP for routing, so it doesn't actually have a subfolder that I can use as a document root. P.S I do have two separate virtual hosts. Notice the ellipses in the code snippet in my question.

Comment: Then you will need to modify the rewrite rules that pass everything into your PHP.   I can't help you with than because you didn't include them in your question.  Please edit your question to provide more information (your entire virtual host and .htaccess files are probably needed.)